# zClip not copying specific ID's text

Tags: php, jquery, flash, zclip

I have set up links that when clicked I want it to copy the text. It outputs many links so I have to make sure zClip copies the right one:

```
<a class="copy-callbacks" id="coupon-code-copy-<?php echo $couponid ; ?>" href="#"><?php echo $info['coupon'] ; ?></a>
```

This is the jQuery I am using but it is not working:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("a.copy-callbacks").zclip({
        path:'scripts/ZeroClipboard.swf',
        copy: $('#' + myCopyID).text(),
        beforeCopy:function(){
            var myCopyID = $(this).attr("id");  
        },
        afterCopy:function(){
        }
    });

});
```

Using this code the flash object doesn't even load. I'm not quite sure what is going wrong. I've tried using:

```
copy: $(this).text(),
```

The flash object loads, but for some weird reason it copies some text in the footer. Any help is greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never had to use the .attr("id"), I always do the following.

```
<span class="swfTitle" style="position: relative; onmouseover="this.style.cursor='pointer'">
    Text
</span>

    $('.swfTitle').zclip({
    path: '/js/ZeroClipboard.swf',
    copy: function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            async: false,
            data: JSON.stringify(PageInfo),
            url: "dosomethinghere.aspx&query=string",
            timeout: 30000,
            success: function (data) {
                PageInfo = JSON.parse(data);
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                alert(xhr.status);
                alert(thrownError);
            }
        });
  return PageInfo.PostHTML;
  }
```

Where PageInfo is a js object. Overall, id tags are different than the class tags, .swfTitle is different than #swfTitle.